# what is alternative to executeQueryWithResultSet() in ArangoDb 3.0.2?

Tags: arangodb

I am using **ArangoDb 3.0.2**.

I want to execute query similar to this method

```
executeQueryWithResultSet()
```

which used to work well in Arangodb 2.3.

**What is alternative for this method for Arango 3.0.2 and what are its parameters?**

This [Official Java tutorial](https://www.arangodb.com/tutorials/tutorial-java/) is still using the old method, which when I am trying with Arango 3.0.2 giving me error.

Thanks..!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for [so] as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `executeAqlQuery()` which returns you `CursorResult<T>` or you can use `executeDocumentQuery()` which returns you `DocumentCursor<T>`.

Use `executeDocumentQuery()` only if your query returns you a document or a list of documents that extends `DocumentEntity`, otherwise use `executeAqlQuery()`.

The Java tutorial is not up to date, but you can find the updated and correct sources for the tutorial [here](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb-java-driver/blob/master/src/test/java/com/arangodb/example/FirstProject.java#L139).